# Unable to load any iframe in local file?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I created the following file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        iframe {
            height: 500px;
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="www.youtube.com">
  </body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to load any site into an iframe, just for testing with how iframes work. But no matter what URL I place in the `src` attribute, I get the same result when I open this file in a browser:

[image]

The content of the iframe body becomes this:

[image]

It seems to be a sort of generic chrome error. There are no errors in the console. It is not a security measure by the domains I'm trying to load.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you doing this from `file://` protocol perhaps? Also check browser dev tools network for clues. And some sites have framebuster headers that won't let them be loaded in iframes

Comment: I am, yes. Are iframes incompatible with that protocol? The second two things I already ruled out.

Comment: Never tried it but there are security restrictions in `file://` protocol for ajax requests as an example so iframe wouldn't surprise me either. Very easy to spin up  a localhost server to prevent such issues. Many IDE's have built in servers also or extensions for locl servers

Comment: You also wrote src="www.youtube.com" instead of src="https://...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello temporary_user_name,

It is not uncommon for some sites to refuse connections from iframes, youtube is one of these.

I was able to load a page from microcenter using the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      iframe {
        height: 1000px;
        width: 1000px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      src="https://www.microcenter.com/product/601585/970-evo-500gb-v-nand-m2-2280-pcie-nvme-30-x4-internal-solid-state-drive"
    >
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: 
In the screenshot you provided, if you mouse over the iframe it should ideally show "youtube.com refused to connect" if I am correct.

Edit:  I should also note that you normally do have to include the full url, either http:// or https://

Edit2: Since some people had some questions about why some sites block iframes For some more information on this check out https://ziplineinteractive.com/blog/how-to-prevent-a-website-from-being-loaded-in-an-iframe/ . It's an article about how to prevent the loading of your site in an iframe and why.

Comment: It's not YouTube specific. He said he is trying to load any URL. The issue is he's loading it from a page running locally in the browser off his computer.

Comment: I can load the above url (the microcenter one) from a local file, in Chrome, with no problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wasn't youtube-specific. Yet tbauer428 is correct; the url he's using works correctly. So I guess it IS specific actions by the sites I tried loading-- all of them.

Comment: I tested mine from Chrome on my MacBook, had no issues (100% local).  If the issue is with how their Chrome is configured then we would need to know how theirs is set up.  My guess is that the test sites he was using were like google, youtube, facebook, etc.  Most of these sites will refuse to display in an iframe.

Comment: The majority of websites come with 'X-Frame-Options' headers that don't allow them to be loaded in iframes, objects etc from different domains.

Comment: When I add `https://` I am able to load some websites, but not youtube because their security team actually knows what they're doing. So that was part of the issue. Side note, closing the iframe tag has no bearing on this.

Comment: Okay I wasn't sure, I mostly build sites in React so am used to having closing tags for most everything. I will amend my answer :)